# Use Dropzone.js with Vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, dropzone.js

I am trying to use Dropzone.js within a Rails form that is generated via Vue.js. I've placed the **dropzone.js** file in app/assets/javascripts/.

I then created a single-file **components/dropzone.vue** component as such:

```
<template>
  <div id="image-drop"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        greeting: 'blah'
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#image-drop", { url: "/file/post"});
    }
  }
</script>

<style></style>
```

I call this component from my main vue file:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';
import dropzone from 'components/dropzone';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const listingForm = new Vue({
    el: '#listing-multistep',
    data: {
      activeStep: 0
    },
    components: { dropzone }
  })
})
```

and in my Rails **_form.html.erb** partial I have

```
<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 0">
  ...
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 1">
  ...
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 2">
  ...
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 3">
  <h2>Images</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <dropzone></dropzone>
  </div>
</fieldset>

...

<button type="reset" @click="activeStep--" :disabled="activeStep === 0"/>
  Previous
</button>

<button type="reset" @click="activeStep++" :disabled="activeStep === stepList.length - 1"/>
  Next
</button>
```

But Dropzone is not being initialized on `<div id="image-drop">`.
Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first reading this question, I thought you had already created a wrapper component, because it uses `<dropzone></dropzone>`. But from the fiddle linked below, that doesn't appear to be the case. When using an external library with Vue, typically you want to wrap the external library functionality in a Vue component. Here is a *very* basic example.

```
Vue.component("dropzone",{
  template: `<div></div>`,
  mounted(){
    new Dropzone(this.$el, {
        url: "/file/post"
    })
  }
})
```

[Here is a pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EwXzOw) demonstrating the component.

Dropzone emits [many events](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list), that you may want to customize this basic component to listen to and emit to Vue so that it knows about things that happened.

**Original Answer**

When the component is created, `div#image-drop` does not yet exist.

Use `mounted`.

See the [lifecycle diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

As mentioned below, since you are hiding parts of the template, you may want to switch to `v-show` instead of `v-if`. The difference being that `v-show` renders the hidden elements to the DOM, but hides them, whereas `v-if` doesn't render them until they are needed.

If you want to stick with `v-if` you would need to add a `watch` to `activeStep`.

```
watch:{
  activeStep(newVal){
    if (3 == newVal)
      this.$nextTick(() => new Dropzone("div#image-drop", { url: "/file/post"}))
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see that creates the `class="dz-clickable"` so I think it's being mounted now, but I see no Dropzone field (i.e. the actual dropzone area)

Comment: I think it might have to do with the fact that this is a multi-step form, and this image drop is within a `v-if` conditional so Vue must take it out of the DOM entirely or something, so perhaps Dropzone cannot reconnect to the `div#image-drop` element?

Comment: @DaniG2k It's difficult to say without a working example. But yes, if the div you are creating the dropzone on is inside a v-if, then it literally might not exist in the DOM when component is mounted. You might want to watch whatever the v-if depends on and create the dropzone in the handler.

Comment: I'll update my question with a bit more details as I'm not sure how to watch for the DOM creation.

Comment: Try to use v-show instead of v-if, v-show will render the element but it will be hidden. v-if won't create a DOM element until required.

Comment: @cassioscabral Agreed, that should be another viable alternative.

Comment: `v-show` was giving me other problems :( so I was previously told to use `v-if` instead

Comment: I just tried with `v-show` now but the form steps stop displaying entirely...that was the problem.

Comment: @DaniG2k I updated the answer with the alternatives. I don't know why v-show would cause you issues.

Comment: Still can't get it to work...would it help if I create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @DaniG2k Yes it would.

Comment: I got a JSFiddle working!! https://jsfiddle.net/DaniG2k/kjbnfu1v/5/
Oddly, if I substitute the v-if with v-show in the fiddle, it's working without a problem but if I do the same on my local environment it stops working. Anyways, if you could help me get Dropzone working on the last step (images) I'd be grateful. I've removed the single-file component for simplicity and put all the code directly in the main Vue instance. You can see it in the `created` function.

Comment: @DaniG2k I updated the answer with a component that may help.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much it worked. I actually think I'd gotten it working already but the map was not appearing as I hadn't set the style to have a height. There are still several problems with this approach, such as the fact that every time I load the component it creates a new input element: `<input multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept="image/*" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;" type="file">`. I'll see if I can rewrite the form to use v-show instead of v-if